# Apache with more than one PHP version

Tags: 20.04, php, vps

I have Apache and PHP 7.4 installed on my Ubuntu 20 server on VPS. But I also need to have PHP 7.0 for one project which does not run on Php 7.4.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sometimes people go solving this by installing Vagrant boxes (in e.g. Virtualbox) with different setups within. https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search In professional / agency environment it's common that (larger) projects have their own virtual machine setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have only one version of PHP loaded as Apache module.
However, you can install another version of PHP and use it in CGI mode for selected directories. The Apache configuration for this will be a bit complicated, but it seems doable.

Comment: Thank you. May be it is time to rewrite the code for php 7.4